# How to update field on one table based on field in another table in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Good morning,

I'm designing a database in Access 2010 to track inventory. It specifies a bin location for each item that is tracked. Each product will always associated with one bin, and no bin will be associated with more than one product (but can be associated with 0 products). Products may move to a different bin at any given time, and I need to be able to search/filter/etc. by either bin location or product name.

Currently, I have a form that will display several different fields for one record (product) at a time. In it I've included a combo box whose control is a query that provides a list of all empty bins. This combo box will be used to select a bin location for a product, and updates the `[CurrentInventory].[Bin]` field. When `[CurrentInventory].[Bin]` is updated I would like two other tasks completed as well:

1. Update `[Bins].[AName]` with the same value contained in
   `[CurrentInventory].[AName]` where the value of `[Bins].[Bin]` is the same as `[CurrentInventory].[Bin]`.
2. Clear the previous value of `[Bins].[AName]` in the record where
   `[Bins].[Bin]` equals the previous value of
   `[CurrentInventory].[Bin]`. This is so the previous bin will show as empty and become available for another product.

I'm not very experienced with Access yet, and have limited experience with both Macros and VB, so I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access 2010 (and newer) you can accomplish your objective by using an After Update event-driven data macro on the [CurrentInventory] table:

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

For more information on Data Macros, see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Comment: @chrisleav You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/913828/inventory.zip).

Comment: What are the chances you can also help me find a way to ensure that a value is entered for `[AName]` before a bin is selected on new records? I tried setting `Nz([AName],0)<>0` as a validation rule on the Bin field in the form, but that didn't work. I tried adding a step ahead of your macro, which also didn't work: 

`If IsNull({CurrentInventory].[AName]) Then
Raise Error
  Error Number (001)
  Error Description (Please enter a name before selecting a bin.)
StopMacro`

What should I do differently?

Comment: @chrisleav If new records must always have an [AName] then you can just open the table in Design View and set the `Required` property of that field to `Yes`. Would that suffice?

Comment: [AName] and several other fields are currently required. The problem is, when I'm creating a new record, [AName] is not updated on the Bins table; the macro above only works on existing records. Would we be able to, say, set up a validation rule on [CurrentInventory].[Bin] to ensure [AName] is not null, and have the record saved when [CurrentInventory].[AName] is updated? Or maybe hide/disable the Bin field until the record is saved.

Comment: @chrisleav I'm puzzled. If [AName] is Required (at the table level) then Access won't let you commit the new record if [AName] is empty (Null). If the commit fails then the AfterUpdate macro won't run (because no update took place). Is [CurrentInventory].[AName] *really* defined as `Required` = `Yes` in the table definition?

Comment: [CurrentInventory].[AName] is required at the table level. The issue is not in the table [CurrentInventory], it is in [Bins]. When I'm adding a new record to [CurrentInventory], [Bins].[AName] is not updated unless I first save the record without [Bin] selected, then return and select a bin. So what I need is a way to have Access save at least the [CurrentInventory].[AName] field before allowing a Bin to be selected so that your macro updates [Bins].[AName], while preferrably allowing [CurrentInventory].[Bin] to remain a required field. I hope this is a little more clear!

Comment: @chrisleav Oh, okay. The problem is that the AfterUpdate macro only runs after updates to existing records, You'll have to put some similar logic in the AfterInsert macro to handle the insertion of new records.

Comment: @chrisleav Updated working example available [here](http://wikisend.com/download/251306/inventory_v2.zip). It uses a Named Macro that gets called from both the After Insert and After Update macros to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help. Due to the nature of my work environment, I won't be able to download that file here, but I will do so once I'm home, try it out, and report back to you tomorrow. I appreciate your time!

Comment: Mr. Thompson, you are the man! Those macros do exactly what I need them to. Thanks a bunch!